# Is running a game at a higher resolution more stressful on CPU/GPU full screen or windowed?

Tags: cpu, gpu, window, fullscreen, rendering

When running a game at a high resolution (1920 by 1200) is it more stressful on CPU/GPU when it is full screen (1920 by 1200), or windowed (e.g. 1280 by 1024)?

What about if another window is open while the game is running?

Comment: What exactly is your concern about stress, and you say a bit more about that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**When running a game at a high resolution (1920 by 1200) is it more stressful on CPU/GPU when it is full screen (1920 by 1200), or windowed (e.g. 1280 by 1024)?**

It is more stressful to run the game windowed, as you are actually drawing the desktop in the background along with the game window. This is offset however by your lower resolution when the game is windowed, which requires the GPU to make fewer operations to render your game's video output. It's a tradeoff and may be beneficial in some cases.

**What about if another window is open while the game is running?**
Again, with another window, you will be drawing/executing whatever is going on in that window.

**Personally:**
I prefer full-screen applications when I can so that I'm not wasting CPU/GPU cycles on unnecessary applications. If your GPU?CPU struggles to game at full 1080p, you may be stuck to windowed mode to increase FPS. Just downsize any Aero effects and make sure that there are no extra processes running in the background (anti-virus etc).